# Python Matplotlib Assigning boundaries to the built-in colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to assign maximum and minimum values to the [built-in colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) in matplotlib.

This is the code for the colormap:

```
im = ax.imshow(frame, cmap='inferno', interpolation = "bilinear")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

The argument, *frame*, is currently a 4 x 16 array, which is then converted to colors, but the problem is the colormap maximum and minimum is generated in respect to the maximum and minimum of the given data.

If the maximum of a dataset is 20, it will make that area very red. However if I then run this with another dataset that has a maximum of 100, it will make that the reddest. How can I limit the cmap color bounds so that it will always have a consistent maximum and minimum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you get norm? did you try [`LogNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LogNorm.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)?

Comment: Oops sorry, I was testing out bounded cmaps, so currently my norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand well your question so my comment was useless and i deleted it. i don't know how to provide a simple answer to your problem. maybe you can extract the colors of a cmap and make your own consistency through different datasets, but you will need all the min/max in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a question of the correct normalization. The normalization needs to be the same for all plots and in this case should range between the minimum and maximum value of all data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3),np.linspace(-3,3,80))
z1 = np.sin(x)+np.cos(y)
z2 = z1*3
z3 = 2*z1-4

mini = np.min([z1.min(), z2.min(), z3.min()])
maxi = np.max([z1.max(), z2.max(), z3.max()])
norm = plt.Normalize(mini, maxi)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
axes[0].imshow(z1, norm=norm)
axes[1].imshow(z2, norm=norm)
im = axes[2].imshow(z3, norm=norm)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Normalizing was the solution I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

that's not much tested (and even less commented) but i hope you get the idea

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

class IndexedCMap(object):
    """set consistent cmap values through different datasets"""

    def __init__(self, cmap):
        """takes a cmap name or cmap object"""
        if type(cmap) is str:
            self.cmap = get_cmap(cmap)
        else:
            self.cmap = cmap
        self.colorlist = self.cmap.colors


    def set_max(self, data):
        """fix the max values of the max dataset"""
        self.z_max = data.max()
        self.z_min = data.min()


    def get_cmap_subset(self, data):
        """return a cmap consistent to your dataset"""
        norm_z = lambda x: int(self.cmap.N*(x-self.z_min)/(self.z_max-self.z_min))
        d_min = norm_z(data.min())
        d_max = norm_z(data.max())
        return ListedColormap(self.colorlist[d_min:d_max])


"""ad-hoc data"""
x = np.linspace(0,2,100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
z = x**2 + y**2
z = np.sin(2*np.pi*z)
z_bigger = z*3
z_shifted = z/5+2

icmap = IndexedCMap('inferno')
icmap.set_max(z_bigger)
regular_inferno = icmap.get_cmap_subset(z)
shifted_inferno = icmap.get_cmap_subset(z_shifted)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(311)
plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=regular_inferno)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('regular z')

plt.subplot(312)
plt.contourf(x, y, z_shifted, cmap=shifted_inferno)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('shifted z')

plt.subplot(313)
plt.contourf(x, y, z_bigger, cmap='inferno')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('bigger z')

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image: persistent cmap]